# Merging dependent picklist into Visualforce email template?

Tags: visualforce, email-template, dependent-picklist

Is there a limitation merging dependent picklist values into a VF email template? I have a picklist (`Case.Denial_Reason__c`) that is controlled by `Case.Status`.

I can merge values such as status or text fields from Case just fine:

```
{!relatedTo.Case__r.Status} 

{!relatedTo.Case__r.Customer_First_Name__c}
```

**^ these both are merged and displayed ^**

---

However, if I include:

```
{!relatedTo.Case__r.Denial_Reason__c}
```

It's not merged/displayed. I've triple checked FLS is correct for this field. I also included the controlling field with the dependent field, still nothing.

My next thought was to create a text formula field that simply channels the value from `Denial_Reason__c`, i.e. `TEXT(Denial_Reason__c)`:

```
{!relatedTo.Case__r.Temp_Formula_Denial_Reason__c}
```

but it's not merged. However, as soon as I change the formula field's value to be a static string such as `"HELLO"`, the formula field is merged/displayed.

It seems as though anything that uses `Case.Denial_Reason__c` as its true "source" can't be directly merged. I think I'll have to write the value in the `relatedTo` object's trigger handler, unless I'm overlooking something here?

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely baffled as to why this fixed the issue, but here's an explanation for anyone that encounters this post:

The transaction to produce the email from this template looked like this:

1. Update case to meet certain criteria (i.e. Status == _______ )
2. This update caused service-layer Apex for Case **before update** logic to fire, creating a Communication_Job__c record (this is the type the template is `relatedTo`
3. The creation of this Communication_Job__c record fired a workflow, which sent an email alert using the template in the original post. The Case fields were merged in through the Lookup from Communication_Job__c to Case.

Moving the service-layer Apex logic in #2 to **after update** in our handler solved this issue - the dependent picklist in question now appears as expected in the template. This will forever haunt me....

Comment: Missed a closing paren on item 2. Interesting problem.